# P-Values in a weighted regression

Tags: r, p-value, linear-model, weights

I compared results from a weighted linear regression and a regular linear regression with no weights.
To do this I built 2 data frames in a way that they represent the same data, once weighted and once not.
I got the same coefficients but different P-Values due to the fact that when calculating the the P-Values the `R` code uses the `df` considering the number of rows with out fixing according to weights.
My question is a theoretical one: why is it so, why is the P-Value not fixed to get similar results to a data frame with the same data as the weighted data frame?

```
data("mtcars")
#make a random  weits column
weights <- round(runif(length(mtcars[,1]),1,2))
weightedData <- cbind(mtcars, weights)
#add the data to a datafrome with out a weights column
partData <-weightedData[weightedData$weights==2,]
dataNoWeigts <- rbind(weightedData[,1:11],partData[,1:11])
#linear regression with out weights column
basicModel <- lm(paste("mpg~",paste(names(dataNoWeigts)[2:11], collapse = "+"),sep=''), data =dataNoWeigts )
# linear regression with a weights column
weigthsmodel <- lm(paste("mpg~",paste(names(weightedData)[2:11], collapse = "+"),sep=''), data =weightedData, weights = weightedData$weights )
```

Comparing the coefficients I get the same results:

```
   > summary(basicModel)$coefficient[,"Estimate"]
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
17.07222225 -0.15028906  0.01218817 -0.02262652  0.35868063 -3.42062748  0.67913634  0.75543885  3.40437679  0.31466080 -0.33333531 
> summary(weigthsmodel)$coefficient[,"Estimate"]
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt            qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
17.07222225 -0.15028906  0.01218817 -0.02262652  0.35868063 -3.42062748  0.67913634  0.75543885  3.40437679  0.31466080 -0.33333531
```

But the P-Values are different:

```
  > summary(weigthsmodel)$coefficient[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt            qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
  0.3398159   0.8830041   0.4983096   0.2935604   0.8355441   0.1025049       0.3421349   0.7221558   0.1232636   0.8312195   0.6970986 
> summary(basicModel)$coefficient[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt            qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
 0.22243624  0.85079413  0.38674212  0.17942110  0.79073724  0.03688756      0.22465998  0.64946419  0.04884703  0.78528644  0.61881363 
>
```

But if i "fix" the degrees of freedom like so:

```
 fixedWeightsModel <- weigthsmodel
> fixedWeightsModel$df.residual <- basicModel$df.residual
> summary(basicModel)$coefficient[,"Pr(>|t|)"]
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt        qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
 0.22243624  0.85079413  0.38674212  0.17942110  0.79073724  0.03688756  0.22465998  0.64946419  0.04884703  0.78528644  0.61881363
```